# How to scan for a specific color in pdf, then create a shape around it?

Tags: javascript, pdf, image-processing, acrobat

I think I'm in way over my head, but I am a beginner at javascript.

I have a colored pdf and I am trying to write a script that scans for a specific color in the pdf (I will also need to determine what that color is). Then create some kind of indication (perhaps a shape around it so that I can identify it).

I don't think I need to utilize fourier transformation because I only need to scan for a color with a specific hex code instead of a range of that color.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: And you want to do this with Javascript inside of Acrobat? Or Javascript running in some other environment? Are the areas you are looking for part of an image? Line-art? Text? Something else? What have you tried already?

Comment: I'm looking to do this inside of acrobat. I am on a company computer, so I won't be able to install any third party applications without submitting a lengthy report. 

The image is an pdf export of an autocad vector file. So, it should be raster in nature.

I was only able to find mouse over hex color identification code. But i was not able to find anything remotely similar to this in order to model my code off it. I am very new to javascript.

thank you for your help,

Comment: I am trying to identify a dotted green line that is not covered by an additional layer that I overlay on it, to the pixel level.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think this one needs a negative answer. As specified by the OP, he's looking for a solution inside of Acrobat, i.e. using Acrobat JavaScript and without involving additional software.

Looking at the Acrobat Javascript documentation confirms what I thought already; Acrobat Javascript gives you access to lots and lots of aspects of a PDF file, but not to the actual page content objects (with the exception of a roundabout and indirect way for text objects).

So to my knowledge this is not possible inside of Adobe Acrobat with Javascript. You would need a different Javascript library (outside of Acrobat), a separate piece of software or a plug-in for Acrobat.

The last bit would seem promising, but it would also involve installing something on the machine, which is a violation of the original question.